# Facebook App Review Page Public Content got rejected due to bad screencast

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

I want to create a website where users can like one-another's Facebook page posts and get points. After getting points, they can use these points to add their own Facebook page post. When users want to add their post from their page, they select their page and all their posts are displayed so that they can easily choose which post to add. For this purpose, I made use of the Page Public Content Access feature. However, when I submit my app for review I am getting the following:

> Not Approved
>   Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app. Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually.
>   All permissions data must be visibly used within your app. We do not accept permission requests for data that you may decide to use later.
>   Please see our Examples page to learn more about making and submitting a successful screencast.
>   Learn more about testing permissions prior to approval.

but I can't find what is wrong with my submission. I would be glad if you can help. This is how my submission looks like:
**Tell us how you're using this permission or feature**

> My app is for new starters who want their Facebook page to address greater audience. In this app, users can earn points liking posts of one-another's Facebook pages and use these points to advertise posts of their Facebook Pages. I use  Page Public Content Access to help people choose post from all posts that they shared in their Facebook Page. They choose post that they want to display in my website and in this way this post addresses greater audience. First, user chooses his or her Facebook page which the post belongs to, then, all the posts of this Facebook Page are displayed using Page Public Content Access, so that they can choose easily. They choose the post that they want to add to website.

**Demonstrate how your selected platforms will use this permission or feature**

> 1.Click Login in Home page
>   2.Click Facebook and Login your Facebook
>   3.Confirm your Username
>   4.Click Facebook in navbar and Choose "Add Post"
>   5. Choose your page in which you shared the post
>   6. Click "Choose Post" which will display your posts where you can select the post which you want to add to the website
>   7. Choose 10 Points and click Add Post

**MY SCREENCAST VIDEO:**
https://youtu.be/cFTXz8o5cqo

**EDIT: I am using page access token**:
[PICTURE SHOWING THAT I AM USING PAGE ACCESS TOKEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCTZD.png)

Comment: isn´t page public content access for pages you do NOT own?

Comment: it is, I am accessing users' page

Comment: exactly, but if you want to access the page of the user, you don´t need "public" access. you can just access his page with his page token...

Comment: but whenever I try to access I get error "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
      "type": "OAuthException", although I am using user's page access token

Comment: and when my app is in development mode there is no problem, problem arises when app in public, so I think that I need page public content access

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts?access_token={access_token} that is how my request looks like

Comment: then you are most likely not using a page token, as i suggested

Comment: @luschn I edited the question, you can see the picture that I am using page access token

Comment: _“a website where users can like one-another's Facebook page posts and get points”_ - I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to reward users for liking stuff in any way, right? https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5